# Issue fecthing records from MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I am trying to fetch records from MongoDB database using the following Node js code

```
    const getBirthDaysPromise = (date,month) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(URL,{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true},(err,db) => {
            if (err){
                console.log("DB CONNECTION ERROR");
                reject(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                var dbo = db.db("reminders");
                dbo.collection("reminders").find({dob: [date,month]},{projection: {name: 1,gender: 1}}).toArray(function(err,result){
                    if (err){
                        console.log("data fetching error");
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}


    const getBirthDays = async (date,month) => {
        var birthDays;
        try{
            birthDays = await getBirthDaysPromise(date,month);
            return birthDays;
        }catch(error){
            return [{error: error}];
        }finally{
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    }
    
    module.exports = { getBirthDays };
```

And following is the Driver code for the above function

```
MONGO_LIB.getBirthDays(1,1)
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

When I tried to execute the driver code, I neither got the error, nor the result. Also, the execution did not end. Where am I wrong? I have gone through articles online but couldn't figure out the issue. Please help me out. Thank you